# How to generate AllJoyn WinRT component code from AllJoyn introspection interface XML in Windows 10 and VS 2017 CE

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal, alljoyn

I am trying to develop some POCs to understand the AllJoyn capabilities in Windows 10. My platform is Windows 10 with VisualStudio 2017. **Now the AllJoyn Studio extension is not available for VS 2017** (it is available for VS 2015). So what are the possible ways to generate the code from the Introspection XML interface files. I tried to check if it is possible to use the alljoyncodegen.exe tool but I cannot find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64. The [AllJoyn samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AllJoyn) under the Windows Universal Samples released by Microsoft has the [WinRT component code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AllJoyn/Common) already generated and packaged with the solution. I could not find a documentation on how the code was generated from the introspection xml files.

So essentially what I am trying to figure out is how do you generate the AllJoyn component code from the Introspection XML interface definition files using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition?